# How to sort by category for the label in Blogger

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

I have a lot of Label of post in blogger: US, Japan, Drama, Comedy, Sci-fi, Cartoon,... and

```
<ul class='filminfo-fields'>
  <li>
    <b>Genre: </b>
    <div class='info'>
      <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
        <a expr:href='data:label.url + &quot;?max-results=9&quot;' rel='tag'>
          <data:label.name/>
        </a>
      </b:loop>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <b>Country: </b>
    <div class='info'>
      <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
        <a expr:href='data:label.url + &quot;?max-results=9&quot;' rel='tag'>
          <data:label.name/>
        </a>
      </b:loop>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How to sort by category for the label?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
http://yourblogaddress.com/search/label/US

http://yourblogaddress.com/search/label/Japan

http://yourblogaddress.com/search/label/Comedy
```

.....etc (Remember labels are case sensitive)